# Close Thread Before Exit application

Tags: c++, winapi, thread-safety

I want to stop thread before exit main program. Is this code correct? (the simplified example)

```
HANDLE hThread;
BOOL live = TRUE;



DWORD WINAPI Thread ( LPVOID lpParam )
{
..
while(live);
..
}



case WM_DESTROY:
{
live=FALSE;     
WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);
}
```

Comment: You want to stop it, but do you have to stop it?  Is there some database connection or out-of-process server you have to close?  If not, the easiest way to stop a thread on program exit is to exit the program - all your threads will be stopped.

Answer (score 3):

The safest way to synchronize threads is using some of kernel objects. In your case you can create "terminate" event with `CreateEvent` and wait for it inside the thread callback function:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cerr;
using std::endl;

DWORD WINAPI Callback(LPVOID lpVoid)
{
    HANDLE hTerminateEvent = *(reinterpret_cast<HANDLE*>(lpVoid));

    bool terminate = false;

    while(!terminate)
    {
        DWORD retVal = WaitForSingleObject(hTerminateEvent, 0);

        switch(retVal)
        {
            case WAIT_OBJECT_0: 
                cout << "Terminate Event signalled" << endl;
                terminate = true;
                break;
            case WAIT_TIMEOUT:
                cout << "Keep running..." << endl;
                Sleep(1000);
                break;
            case WAIT_FAILED:
                cerr << "WaitForSingleObject() failed" << endl;
                terminate = true;
                break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    DWORD threadID = 0;
    HANDLE hTerminateEvent = CreateEvent(0, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
    HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(0, 0, Callback, &hTerminateEvent, 0, &threadID);  

    // allow some time to thread to live
    Sleep(20000);

    // set terminate event
    if(!SetEvent(hTerminateEvent))
    {
        cerr << "SetEvent() failed" << endl;        
        return 1;
    }

    // wait for thread to terminate
    DWORD retVal = WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);

    switch(retVal)
    {
        case WAIT_OBJECT_0: 
            cout << "Thread terminated" << endl;            
            break;
        case WAIT_FAILED:
            cerr << "WaitForSingleObject() failed" << endl;         
            break;
    }

    CloseHandle(hThread);
    CloseHandle(hTerminateEvent);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Keep running...
Keep running...
Keep running...
Keep running...
Keep running...
Keep running...
Keep running...
Keep running...
Keep running...
Keep running...
Keep running...
Keep running...
Keep running...
Keep running...
Keep running...
Keep running...
Keep running...
Keep running...
Keep running...
Keep running...
Terminate Event signalled
Thread terminated
```

Comment: I use similar code, but I call `WaitForSingleObject` with a rather long delay, say 5s (`5000`), log a message saying the thread is hung if I get a `WAIT_TIMEOUT`, `WaitForSingleObject` some more and then simply exit and let Windows clean up. Using `INFINITE` might prevent your process from exiting.

Answer (score 2):

In order to ensure the thread sees the change made to `live` you need to make `live` `volatile`:

```
volatile BOOL live = TRUE;
```

Comment: as additional advice - pack the management of all this into a RAII object. It's a best practice for c++ to manage resources using such kinds of objects.

Comment: Note that this is a Windows-specific trick. On most platforms, the behavior of `volatile` in C and C++ with respect to threads is unspecified.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not correct. You have nothing that guarantees the thread will ever see the change. The compiler is free to optimize:

```
DWORD WINAPI Thread ( LPVOID lpParam )
{
..
while(live);
..
}
```

to:

```
DWORD WINAPI Thread ( LPVOID lpParam )
{
..
register bool temp=live;
while(temp);
..
}
```

That obviously won't work.

The rule of thumb is this -- **never** access a variable in one thread while another thread might be modifying it unless you use some specific mechanism to ensure the operation is safe. If you follow that rule, you'll stay out of trouble.

Comment: I would down-vote you, but I'm going to see other peoples' opinions. I really don't believe that a compiler is free to do that, only on a local variable. Can you please post example disassembled or article?

Comment: Why wouldn't the compiler be free to do that? Can you post any strictly-conforming C++ code that could tell the difference? If no, then the compiler is free to do that. Unless some other standard prohibits it, which none does. This is the very most basic thing you must understand when you start writing multithreaded code.

Comment: Arguments from ignorance are fairly...ignorant.

Comment: It's not an argument from ignorance. A C++ compiler is permitted to make any optimization a strictly-confirming C++ program cannot detect. There is no strictly-conforming code that could detect the difference, so it's free to make it. Again, this is the very first thing every multithreaded programmer learns and it can't be fully taught in a comment.

Comment: @David, Even if you use locks, for the sake of argument, they are "accessed" in different threads at the same time. Assignment to primitive types (such as a bool) should be atomic by default; isn't it? Can you think of "corrupted" assignment to a boolean?

Comment: @Jaywalker Do you mean the locks themselves are accessed at the same time? The whole point of locks is to avoid accessing things at the same time. The lock itself uses a special platform-specific mechanism to synchronize across threads (which varies depending on the type of lock and the platform). The issue here is not atomicity, it's visibility, which is a completely different issue. Absent some synchronization mechanism, the platform is free to optimize out the repeated memory access. (Otherwise, no C++ program could ever store anything but a purely local value in a register. YUCK!)

Comment: I think @Jaywalker's point was that, if theread 1 released a lock, thread 2 ACQUIRED that lock while thread one waited, and then updated the variable, and then thread 2 released the lock, thread 1 got it, and then read the variable, how would the compiler know that they were related? How would the compiler know that it was some bool variable they were locking and thus keep it in memory instead of in register?

Comment: Two answers: 1) The compiler has to know somehow, otherwise it's not implementing locks properly. We, as programmers, don't have to care how it does it. 2) Generally this is accomplished by making sure the compiler has no idea what the lock functions do. Because the compiler has no idea what the lock functions do, it can't assume that they *themselves* don't modify the variable. In essence, anything another thread could do, the lock functions themselves could do. So the compiler can't, for example, cache variables not purely local in a register across a call.

Comment: Or, to put it more simply, the lock operation would tell the compiler that somehow. Exactly how is up to the implementation. Generally it "just works" (because the compiler can't see into the lock functions anyway), but if you create your own platform-specific locks that inline, you have to use some platform-specific code to *tell* the compiler that -- like a clobber or a memory barrier. (We're getting into me trying to teach all of multithreaded programming in comments. I'll try, but it's hard. This is complex stuff.)

Answer (score 0):

```
void onexxit() {
   /* do-it */
}
```

What about `atexit( onexxit )` function

http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/tze57ck3.aspx